# Apache2 config file path on Ubuntu.

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2, lamp

can someone tell me the path of the Apache2 config file on Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your version of Ubuntu, but newer versions have it in /etc/apache2. The files are apache2.conf and httpd.conf (usually empty)

Comment: This link provides nice tables for different locations on different servers https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should read the Ubuntu [server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf).  It will probably answer most of your beginner questions on getting your web server setup (including the question you asked, which the guide states is in /etc/apache2/).

Comment: @Catfish - I updated the link to their latest server guide.

Comment: Broken again... This works: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf